# WP Mail SMTP Version 1.4.2 stopped sending emails

Tags: php, wordpress, smtp, phpmailer

I have a plugin that uses `wp_mail()` function to send emails on form errors. I have WP Mail SMTP plugin installed as well to use my custom SMTP settings.

Everything was working great for months with WP Mail SMTP version 0.11.1. But ever since I updated the plugin to version 1.4.2, my emails have stopped working.

From what I have figured out, `wp_mail()` is not working inside my plugin only. If I keep it anywhere like in theme files etc, the email is sent immediately. But from inside my plugin, I get this exception every time:

```
  "errors": {
    "wp_mail_failed": [
      "Could not instantiate mail function."
    ]
  },
  "error_data": {
    "wp_mail_failed": {
      "to": [
        "oibrahim@folio3.com"
      ],
      "subject": "Form Error",
      "message": "<dl><dt>Error Logged:<\/dt> <dd>{\"MembershipNumber\":null,\"Success\":false,\"Message\":\"The combination is incorrect\",\"contactInfo\":{\"PrimaryContactNumber\":null,\"AlternateNumber\":null,\"MobileNumber\":null,\"OtherPhone1\":null,\"Email\":null},\"membership\":{\"EffectiveDate\":null,\"ExpiryDate\":null,\"planInfo\":null,\"MembershipSubProgram\":null},\"address\":{\"HomeAddress\":null,\"MailingAddress\":null,\"BillingAddress\":null},\"slxConstantInfo\":[],\"Token\":null}<\/dd><dt>Timestamp:<\/dt> <dd>Monday, April 22nd, 2019 @ 03:16:30 PM<\/dd><dt>Referrer:<\/dt> <dd>renew\/step1<\/dd><dt>User:<\/dt> <dd> \n<br>\n<br>\n<br>\n<\/dd><\/dl>",
      "headers": [

      ],
      "attachments": [

      ],
      "phpmailer_exception_code": 2
    }
  }
}
```

If I downgrade the WP Mail SMTP plugin, things start working fine again. So its a sure shot issue with the plugin. Maybe in my plugin where I call the `wp_mail()` function, the settings of WP Mail SMTP are not already loaded or something like that.

Any quick help will be really appreciated since I have this code running on a production site. Thanks in advance!

Edit: Just to add some details, WP Mail SMTP test email is running fine !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind. I posted on WP MAIL SMTP support forum but got no response. I figured out that the `phpmailer` object is not holding  the modified setting inside my plugin. So this is the work-around I implemented just to make things work, though I know this is not the best fix.

I placed the following action in my plugin's init:

```
/**
 *  Reconfigure SMTP setting to make WP MAIL SMTP plugin work
 */
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'reconfigure_smtp' );
function reconfigure_smtp( $phpmailer ) {
    $SMTPhost = get_option('smtp_host');
    $SMTPport = get_option('smtp_port');
    $FromEmail = get_option('mail_from');
    $FromName = get_option('mail_from_name');
    $phpmailer->isSMTP();     
    $phpmailer->Host =$SMTPhost;
    $phpmailer->Port = $SMTPport;
    $phpmailer->From = $FromEmail;
    $phpmailer->FromName = $FromName;
}
```

This just fetches the options stored by WP MAIL SMTP and then reconfigures the phpmailer instance. Its just a result of desperate need to fix things ASAP.

Answer (score -1):

The `could not instantiate mail function` error means that you don’t have a local mail server installed, but it will only happen if you’re using `mail()` – it will not apply if you are using SMTP. So it sounds like your suspicions are correct – the config for wp_mail has not been loaded for some reason, or the SMTP plugin is not doing what it’s supposed to.

Comment: Can you please suggest a possible solution?

Comment: There's evidently a problem with the plugin, so I suggest you contact the plugin's author.